# Linphone (IOS) Build Error (is invalid in C99)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linphone, linphone-sdk

I downloaded linphone-iphone project from [git](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone) and SDK from ([Liblinphone iOS version 2.4.0](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads)). Than copied **liblinphone-sdk** folder to **project folder**(linphone-iphone-master).

I'm trying to run [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/)(iphone) but I'm getting this error. What should i do?

> /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m:533:51: Implicit declaration of function 'linphone_proxy_config_find_auth_info' is invalid in C99

**Build Settings -> Search Paths**

[image: Search Paths]

**Error from xcode**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Error Log**

> CompileC /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.o Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Werror -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/linphone-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/linphone-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/linphone-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/linphone-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/Utils/NinePatch -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/Utils/XMLRPC -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/DerivedSources -Werror=objc-method-access -Werror=incomplete-implementation -DLINPHONE_CAPABILITY_INAPP_PURCHASE=0 -F/Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -DORTP_LOG_DOMAIN=\"ios\" -include /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/linphone_Prefix-ahtsqvxgrzqakggrtidvlsmngdln/linphone_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.dia -c /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m -o /Users/cansahinbakir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/linphone-dqzmasmedjxmwsauolyepbakaskm/Build/Intermediates/linphone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/linphone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.o
>
> /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m:533:51: error: implicit declaration of function 'linphone_proxy_config_find_auth_info' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                   LinphoneAuthInfo *proxyAi = (LinphoneAuthInfo *)linphone_proxy_config_find_auth_info(proxyCfg);
>                                                                   ^
>   /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m:533:51: note: did you mean 'linphone_proxy_config_get_error_info'?
>   In file included from /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m:1:
>   In file included from /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/linphone_Prefix.pch:10:
>   In file included from /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/Log.h:20:
>   In file included from /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneManager.h:32:
>   In file included from /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/Utils/FastAddressBook.h:23:
>   In file included from /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include/linphone/linphonecore.h:1023:
>   /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include/linphone/linphone_proxy_config.h:366:42: note: 'linphone_proxy_config_get_error_info' declared here
>   LINPHONE_PUBLIC const LinphoneErrorInfo *linphone_proxy_config_get_error_info(const LinphoneProxyConfig *cfg);
>                                            ^
>   /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m:533:31: error: cast to 'LinphoneAuthInfo *' (aka 'struct _LinphoneAuthInfo *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>                   LinphoneAuthInfo *proxyAi = (LinphoneAuthInfo *)linphone_proxy_config_find_auth_info(proxyCfg);
>                                               ^
>   /Users/cansahinbakir/Downloads/linphone-iphone-master/Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m:839:26: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'const LinphoneAuthInfo *' (aka 'const struct _LinphoneAuthInfo *') with an expression of type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
>           const LinphoneAuthInfo *ai = linphone_proxy_config_find_auth_info(config);
>                                   ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   3 errors generated.

XCode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)

**Note** : I'm new on Xcode and IOS.

Thanks for help.